# desktop app using php

Tags: php, desktop

I want to make desktop app using php. I have used flex once and it allows you to run app on dekstop but it requires web server.

So basically I Want a solution that allows me to run application on desktop without a web server. Application needs to be database driven mysql, access whatever.

Comment: have you considered a language like c++, c#, vb, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Thought to point you out to php-gtk but they have a funny news on their site.

Anyway, I have a feeling that you will abandon the idea at the some moment. just because PHP is not Flex and creating desktop applications with it "just because you know PHP" is not a great idea.

Comment: You mean that one: "there are still a few crazy people hacking away"? :D

Answer (score 1):

You should also try to use [Titanium Framework](http://www.appcelerator.com/). It also allows to develope desktop applications with PHP.

Comment: Aaaaaaand, for a quick intro: http://www.slideshare.net/benramsey/desktop-apps-with-php-and-titanium

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/). It allows you to create desktop applications with PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

WinBinder - http://winbinder.org/